# Unable to autoload constant API::KittensController [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api

I'm following a tutorial to learn the basics of API and I'm having troubles setting everything up.
This is what I've done:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  namespace :api, constraints: {format: :json} do
    resources :kittens
  end
end


#app/controllers/api/kittens_controller.rb
class API::KittenController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

end

#config/initializers/inflections.rb
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'API'
end
```

The error I get when visiting /api/kittens

```
Unable to autoload constant API::KittensController, expected /media/Volume.II/Dropbox/Web Development/odin-project/3. Ruby on Rails/odin-kittens/app/controllers/api/kittens_controller.rb to define it

Extracted source (around line #495):

        else
          require_or_load(expanded, qualified_name)
          raise LoadError, "Unable to autoload constant #{qualified_name}, expected #{file_path} to define it" unless from_mod.const_defined?(const_name, false)
          return from_mod.const_get(const_name)
        end
      elsif mod = autoload_module!(from_mod, const_name, qualified_name, path_suffix)
```

Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a typo in your class name: `API::KittenController` instead of `API::KittensController`.

Comment: Can't believe it was that simple. Thanks !